# Error Null pointer. (io.reactivex.Scheduler)' on a null object reference

Tags: android, nullpointerexception

This is my log cat. When i click on specific tab, my app crashes.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'io.reactivex.Flowable io.reactivex.Flowable.observeOn(io.reactivex.Scheduler)' on a null object reference
    at com.example.haji.Fragment.RecentFragment.loadRecents(RecentFragment.java:93)
    at com.example.haji.Fragment.RecentFragment.onCreateView(RecentFragment.java:86)
    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2346)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1428)
```

When i call loadRecents, it give me error. Please help.

```
private void loadRecents() {
    Disposable disposable = recentsRepository.getAllRecents().observeOn(AndroidSchedulers
        .mainThread()).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()).subscribe(new Consumer <List <Recents>>() {
        @Override
        public void accept(List <Recents> recents) throws Exception {
            onGetAllRecentsSuccess(recents);
        }
    }, new Consumer <Throwable>() {
        @Override
        public void accept(Throwable throwable) throws Exception {
            Log.d("Error",throwable.getMessage());
        }
    });
    compositeDisposable.add(disposable);
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your method `recentsRepository.getAllRecents()` return null instead of `Flowable<List <Recents>>`

Comment: Inside your `recentsRepository.getAllRecents()` method (for testing purpose only) return `Flowable.just(new ArrayList<>())`. After that app crash should be fixed. You need only properly implement `recentsRepository.getAllRecents()` method

Comment: Thanks you soo much for help it really helpful

Comment: You are welcome. If it helps, mark it as answer, please, to help other people find solution as fast as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Add this line to Biuld.gradle dependencies

```
dependencies {
     //other code...
     implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.0.2'
}
```

Comment: check import io.reactivex.android.schedulers; for AndroidSchedulers

Answer (score 0):

**error** - null object reference

maybe because you have not initialized

```
 compositeDisposable = new CompositeDisposable();

Databasename databasename= Databasename.getInstance(this);


recentsRepository=RecentsRepository.getInstance(RecentsDataSource.getInstance(mainDatabase.recentsDAO()));
```